# Terms filter doesn't works with bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have mapped on elasticsearch a type called `measure`, which contains both `variableName` and `sensorId` as string.

Mapping.

```
{
    "measures": {
        "mappings": {
            "summarizedmeasure": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "rawValue": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "sensorId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "summaryTimeUnit": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "timestamp": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "variableName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this query it works properly and return all measures for all sensors whose `variableName` is `FORWARD_FLOW`.

```
{
  "query" : { 
     "bool": {
        "must": {
           "match": { "variableName":  "FORWARD_FLOW" }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Query result.

```
{
    "took": 8,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 294409,
        "max_score": 1.0059962,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "measures",
                "_type": "summarizedmeasure",
                "_id": "AU4fKBWcMpd7AZtvgiuS",
                "_score": 1.0059962,
                "_source": {
                    "id": null,
                    "sensorId": "13LA062753",
                    "variableName": "FORWARD_FLOW",
                    "rawValue": "0.01",
                    "value": "0.01",
                    "timestamp": 1434060000000,
                    "summaryTimeUnit": "DAYS"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "measures",
                "_type": "summarizedmeasure",
                "_id": "AU4fKAtqMpd7AZtvgitp",
                "_score": 1.0059962,
                "_source": {
                    "id": null,
                    "sensorId": "13LA062744",
                    "variableName": "FORWARD_FLOW",
                    "rawValue": "0.44",
                    "value": "0.44",
                    "timestamp": 1433973600000,
                    "summaryTimeUnit": "DAYS"
                }
            }.....
```

However, when I use `terms` filter to search only for measures which pertains to specific sensors, it returns no measures.

```
{
   "query":{            
     "filtered":{
        "query" : { 
          "bool": {
            "must": {
               "match": { "variableName":  "FORWARD_FLOW" }
            }
          }
        }, 
        "filter": {"terms":{ "sensorId":["13LA062753","14VD021810"]}}
      }        
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks you.

Comment: are you sure you have documents that contain those `sensorId` values?

Comment: Can you show the mapping for the `sensorId` field as well as one or two sample documents?

Comment: Yes I have documents that contains those `sensorId` values. Check now my edited question.

Comment: what about your mapping? could you show us what `GET /index/type/_mapping` returns?

Comment: Sorry, check now my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `sensorId` `"index": "not_analyzed"` like this:

```
"sensorId": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

This value defaults to `analyzed` and term filters do exact check (the terms are not being ran through an analyzer).

Please refer to [finding exact values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html) for a fuller description why you need to do this.

Either this or you can change the analyzer or lowercase your terms. The problem is that that field is being processed by the default analyzer which lowercases the values. That's why this query would work with your mapping:

```
{
   "query":{            
     "filtered":{
        "query" : { 
          "bool": {
            "must": {
               "match": { "variableName":  "FORWARD_FLOW" }
            }
          }
        }, 
        "filter": {"terms":{ "sensorId":["13la062753","14vd021810"]}}
      }        
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works with lowercase `sensorId` but I think is better change the analyzer

Comment: @Sapikelio that depends, do you need to analyze it?

Comment: Finally I'll opt for parse `sensorId` to lowercase because This data is in production environment and I can´t delete type and re-mapping it. It will not be very difficult because I am using Java api for it. Thanks